# Trying to split string with alphanumeric

Tags: sql

TABLE A

```
ID            Comments
1             John $123
2             Bret $45 33-4ABC
3             HELEN $150-KLR
```

I need output like below

```
ID            Comments              Amount
1             John                  $123
2             Bret                  $45
3             HELEN                 $150
```

Here is my code . my code Give me Amount of bret $45 33-4ABC and helen Amount $150-KLR that really not want. it should be $45 and $150. in other words any space or (-) after $45 or $150 etc has to off.

Thanks In Advance

```
SELECT id,

REPLACE(Comments,SUBSTRING(Comments,
  PATINDEX('%[$,0-9]%',Comments),
  Len(Comments)),'') AS Comments,
  SUBSTRING(Comments,PATINDEX('%[$,0-9]%',Comments),
  LEN(Comments)) As Amount

from table A
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, this works on the data you provided:

```
select a.*, v.comments, left(v.rest, patindex('%[^$0-9]%', rest + ' ') - 1) as amount
from a cross apply
     (values (rtrim(left(comments, charindex('$', comments + '$') - 1)),
              stuff(comments, 1, charindex('$', comments + '$') - 1, '')
             )
     ) v(comments, rest);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=44b3b3ec31c841c2285f6ee76568cc90) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi Gordon, i am using SQL SERVER 2016 and above code is not running in 2016. give me an error of "Trim is not a recognized built-in function". any way out please?

Comment: Now another error message "Invalid Length parameter passed to the LEFT or Substring."  but your above code is excellent

Comment: @Salman81 . . . That is because not all your data looks like the data in the question.  In particular, some rows don't have `'$'`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. In "comments" column some of values are NULL, any way out please?. much appreciated.

Comment: @Salman81 . . . I don't understand.  This should return `NULL` if the value is `NULL`.

Comment: Hi Gordon. In my real project its not working. Because when id =4 and comments column null then it fails. My apology i must add a record which doest not have’$’ and have null.in comments column having Null. Getting error “ invalid length parrameter is passed to left or substring”. I am just stuck here.thanks in advance

Comment: @Salman81 . . . Perhaps you should ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: Yes i post a new question. But your answer  for my above question is perfect and the best.Thank you